# How to take partial trace of a $n - 1$ qubit subsystem from a $n$ qubit system

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I would like to calculate the expression $$ \text{Tr}_2\left\{R^z \sigma\right\}\,,$$ where $$\sigma = \rho \otimes |0\rangle \langle0|^{{\otimes}n}\,.$$ Here $$R = \sum{\theta_m}G_m\,,$$ $$\theta_m \in \mathrm{R}\,,$$ $$G_m \in P\,,$$ where, $P \in \left\{i( \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3 \cdots \sigma_n) \right\}$.

Here, partial trace means that we need to trace out that subsystem of ancilla after solving. Can anybody show a way and here $z > 1$ .

Comment: see eg https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23434/55